# How to change the 'internal IP address' of a Juniper SRX210H

Tags: router, dhcp, ip-address, juniper, junos

How do I change the 'internal IP address' (Not the WAN IP) (192.168.1.1) to something else via the 'Juniper Web Device Manager'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong with Chopper's instructions per se, the SRX210 does not have a dedicate management interface. Out of the box, it will have port 0 configured as a WAN DHCP client, and all the rest of the ports as ethernet switching on VLAN0, and VLAN0 will have the IP 192.168.1.1. You'll want to login to J-Web, go to the configure tab, on the left side find VLANs and adjust theIP of the default VLAN. You may also need to adjust some other things like DHCP service pools to provide addresses on whatever subnet you change to. FYI.

Comment: Ah, I managed to find this after trying to follow Chopper's instructions. This is exactly what I did actually, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [online manual](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security11.1/junos-security-admin-guide/index.html), not many clicks away from Google;

1. In the J-Web user interface, select Configure>System Properties>Management Access.
2. Click Edit. The Edit Management Access dialog box appears.
3. Select the Management tab.
4. If you want to enable an IPv4 address for the device, select IPv4 address and enter a corresponding management port, subnet mask, and default gateway.
5. Click OK to save the configuration or Cancel to clear it.